# Как можно заменить данный код?

Tags: java

Вот у меня есть есть `ArrayList<Integer> list1`, заполненный некоторыми данными и пустой `ArrayList<Integer> list2`
Мне нужно скопировать элементы `list1` в `list2` так, чтобы в `list2` отправились элементы лишь с такими индексами, которые лежат между 10 и 50.

Есть ли более красивое решение, чем просто присвоение через цикл?

Comment: А чем плохо присвоение через цикл? Думаете, библиотечные функции сделают _существенно_ лучше?

Comment: Просто читабельность, мне кажется, лучше будет..
Начал поднимать этот вопрос исключительно из-за "красивости"

Comment: @Stas0n: тогда можно выделить код в отдельную функцию. Будет читабельно.

Comment: Не, ну это слишком)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arraycopy` не пробовали? Можно почитать  немного матчасти [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128269/)

**update:**

Копировать можно вот такой конструкцией (где `a` исходный массив, в `b` добавляем)

```
b.addAll(a.subList(fromIndex, toIndex));
```

`addAll` еще имеем одну модификацию, позволяя вставлять в нужную позицию.

Comment: Я почитал про этот метод, но разве он не для массивов только?

Comment: да. Но разве это проблема?

Comment: мне нужно работать именно со списками. Не хочется переводить список в массив, дальше работать с ним и обратно в список

Comment: > Не хочется переводить список в массив, дальше работать с ним и обратно в список.

А в чем проблема? Всего-то делов: `Arrays.asList(list1);`

Answer (score 0):

Если бы были не примитивы - можно было бы переопределить метод `clone()` или `Collection.copy(...);` наверно и сейчас это можно сделать, но проще будет все таки просто пройтись циклом.

Comment: неужели нет метода, который копировал бы элементы одного списка в другой, индексы которых лежат в нужно диапозане?

Comment: [Очевидно](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#method_summary), что нет.